# Using javax.xml.ws.Endpoint with HTTPS

Tags: java, soap, https

I'm working on a project to control light and heating in buildings. The backend (written in Java) will run on a Mac Mini and should be accessible via SOAP.

I want to keep the complexity of this project to a minimum because I don't want everyone using it having to set up an application server. So up till now I worked with javax.xml.ws.Endpoint:

```
 Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.create(frontendInterface);
 String uri = "http://"+config.getHost()+":"+config.getPort()+config.getPath();

 endpoint.publish(uri);
```

This works surprisingly well (hey, when did you last see something in Java working with just 3 lines of code?), but now I'm looking for a way to use HTTPS instead of HTTP.

Is there a way to do this without using an application server or is there another way to secure this connection?

Greetings,
Marek

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For server:

```
SSLContext ssl = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

KeyManagerFactory keyFactory = KeyManagerFactory                    .getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

store.load(new FileInputStream(keystoreFile),keyPass.toCharArray());

keyFactory.init(store, keyPass.toCharArray());


TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

trustFactory.init(store);

ssl.init(keyFactory.getKeyManagers(),
trustFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

HttpsConfigurator configurator = new HttpsConfigurator(ssl);

HttpsServer httpsServer = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port), port);

httpsServer.setHttpsConfigurator(configurator);

HttpContext httpContext = httpsServer.createContext(uri);

httpsServer.start();

endpoint.publish(httpContext);
```

For client, be sure you do this:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "password");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
//done to prevent CN verification in client keystore
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
   @Override
   public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
     return true;
   }
});
```

Comment: Not verifying the hostname (with this `HostnameVerifier` which lets anything through) is removing an important step to securing the communication. Don't do it!

Comment: Please note that the second argument in HttpsServer.create is "the maximum number of queued incoming connections to allow on the listening socket" according to: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpsServer.html

Comment: the 'uri' variable needs to be something like '/contextPath/ or '/'. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. Error message was no handler found for context. On jre8

Comment: update, i got it working. when cxf is on the classpath, this doesn't work due to java spi changes