# Configure SSL programatically for restful webservice using CXF frontend?

Tags: ssl, cxf, configure

I have a question about configuring SSL programatically for CXF frontend using javax.xml.ws.Provider.

Basically I have implemented a simple Restful webservice like

```
@WebServiceProvider()
@ServiceMode(value = Service.Mode.PAYLOAD)
public class RestWebServiceProvider implements Provider<DOMSource> {
    ...
}
```

And published it with code like

```
public class RestServer {

    protected RestServer() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Starting Server");
        Endpoint e = Endpoint.create(HTTPBinding.HTTP_BINDING, new RestWebServiceProvider() );
        String address = "http://localhost:9000/rest/test";
        e.publish(address);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        new RestServer();
        System.out.println("Server ready...");

        Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
        System.out.println("Server exiting");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

exactly like the restful_dispatch sample project from CXF download's samples folder.

Now what I am trying to achieve is configure SSL of this programatically rather than using XML.

Why? So SSL can be configured at runtime from browser without restarting web app.

I have done some homework and saw the sample project /jax_rs/basic_https is doing it like

```
 static {
    // set the configuration file
    SpringBusFactory factory = new SpringBusFactory();
    Bus bus = factory.createBus("ServerConfig.xml");
    BusFactory.setDefaultBus(bus);
}
```

in Server class where ServerConfig.xml defines the actual SSL config. But that's not flexible enough for my use case.

I have done some digging on stackoverflow and the best link I found seems to from [javax.xml.ws.Endpoint with HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621313/using-javax-xml-ws-endpoint-with-https)

Haven't tried that approach myself but was wandering if that is what you experts did or if there is a better way.

Has anyone done something like this before and care to share a few pointers?

Thanks

Sam