# Using SSL with Soap on java, No servlet

Tags: java, soap, ssl

I was following a fairly useful online tutorial to create a soap server that used mysql to call a stored procedure. This worked quite well and I got code that would respond correctly using a program like SoapUI. The code is as below:

```
@WebService
public class test {

@WebMethod
public String login(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    String DBusername = "test";
    String DBpassword = "test";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, DBusername, DBpassword);

    Statement stmt = null;
    String query = " CALL authorize_user('" + username + "','" + password + "')";

    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String login = rs.getString("au_result");

            if (login != null)
                return login;
            else {
                return "Login Failed";
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
        }
    }
    return "Login Failed";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    test test = new test();
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.publish("http://localhost/testing", test);
}
```

}

So this works when you put in a username and password that is in the DB it will return a positive result. This is only test code, because of the possibility of injection into the code the way its set up now, but that will be changed shortly.

However I am attempting to find a way to use SSL for this server, and the only information I'm able to find is how to use SSL when using a wrapper program or some servlet wrapper to create the soap server. We don't want to go this way at this point, unless we can find a very very good reason to waste the time learning the new code. How would I go about using an SSL connection for this code without using any third party code? We already have a cert from a reputable company that is running on our server for our regular website.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621313/using-javax-xml-ws-endpoint-with-https?

Comment: Don't forget to call .close() on the Connection ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you consider non programming solution?

Just put Apache with SSL as reverse proxy before your web server.

- You don't need to write a line of code (less possibilities for security bugs)
- You get SSL
- You get balancer (if you need it)
- You get caching (if you need it)
  and so on

Answer (score 1):

You have included a code that connects to the database to validate user ID and password (last step in my example below) which is kind of confusing because as I understand that's not what you need help with. Let me understand your architecture first (I hope this is how WE ALL start designing data architecture to safeguard user ID stores).

```
web-app -> user authentication client
   ---->{SOAP CALL}--->
       SSL-proxy-of-some-sort -> SOAP server -> User Authentication Service -> user ID database.
```

Is this correct representation? If yes, I am assuming that you want to keep user password store in a separate data store buried behind firewalls and accessible only using SOAP to avoid "Living Social" situation (50 million user IDs and passwords are stolen by hackers) where there is no possibility of hackers being able to access data store through some soft of SQL injection or other vulnerabilities. If this correct understanding?

Now for the most part, I agree with Victor Ronin's response above that you should consider using Apache server with SSL to front your "soap server". However, even to access that SSL wrapped SOAP server (doesn't matter how you do it), you will still need to write Java code that can handle this SSL communication. I suggest you look into this post (not mine) to see if that helps.

http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/ssl.html

By the way, unless you are going across WAN for this authentication, I cannot imagine needing SSL encryption.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use Handler Chains, this way the handler chain will be executed before any of your soap calls and you can discard any message that doesn´t fit to whatever thing you want to do.

More info on howTo here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.wsfep.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftwbs_jaxwshandler.html